# Java override method doesn't work

Tags: java, overriding, classpath

**Thanks for all of you. In fact someone has put a patch for that class which disturbed the correct behaviour. 
Finally I found this by checking the classloader.
Forgive me:)**

Here, `public class Son` extends `public class Parent` extends `public class GrandParent`

In Parent, this method overrides GrandParent:

```
@Override
public String getSomething() {
    return "blabla";
}
```

In Son, the same method overrides Parent:

```
@Override
public String getSomething() {
    return null;
}
```

It's strange that when I run getSomething() of an object declared as GrandParent and constructed as Son, it goes into the code of Parent and returns "blabla" instead of null.

Has anyone seen this problem before ? Can anyone give an explanation on this ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling that method for a Son instance?

Comment: Can you show us how are you implementing them ? the class implementing `Parent`

Comment: Yes I'm sure, and I see clearly that's a Son in DEBUG view..

Comment: can you also show how exactly you declare and initilize the son and how you call the method ?

Comment: There is no chance for that to happen. Please show us how you are building the instances.

Comment: I would say this isn't possible. You'll have to post the code of classes, and the code which you use to test this, for us to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try this simple code:

```
public class GrandParent
{
    public String f() {
        return "grand parent";
    }
}

public class Parent extends GrandParent
{
    @Override public String f() {
        return "parent";
    }
}

public class Son extends Parent
{
    @Override public String f() {
        return "son";
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GrandParent p = new Son();
        System.out.println(p.f());
    }
}
```

you'll see that the printed out string is `"son"`. You're doing something wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It should work even with parent instance check out:

```
public class Parent {
    public String getSomething()
    {
        return "parent";
    }
}

public class Son extends Parent {

    @Override
    public String getSomething() {
        return "son";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Son son = new Son();
        System.out.println(son.getSomething());
        Parent par = (Parent)son;
        System.out.println(par.getSomething());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
son
son
```